# While Reading Two Videos : poll error 1: No space left on device?

Tags: device, gstreamer, polling, v4l2

While reading two camera's by using gstreamer below pipline,

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink
```

I am not able to read both two camera's at a time. I can read only one camera at a time. While reading both camera's below error came,

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Could not read from resource.
Additional debug info:
gstv4l2bufferpool.c(1023): gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_poll (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
poll error 1: No space left on device (28)
```

**What is the problem here? And how can it be resolved? How will i read both camera's at a time?**

Comment: check the presence of that file /dev/video1 .. or check if you have rights to access it.. also check if you really do not have problem with device space (try df or whatever tool you want)

Comment: how to check whether my PC had a problem with device space or not?
while executing the command df -h

Comment: While executing the df -h:

/dev/sda4        66G   57G  6.1G  91% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  1.1M  395M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G   24M  2.0G   2% /run/shm
none            100M   40K  100M   1% /run/user

Comment: and still you see tha same error (you certainly have space on device )

Comment: still getting the same error, is this because of 91% used space on disk?

Answer (score 0):

> poll error 1: No space left on device (28)

This Error points to Bandwidth limitation on the USB. Especially with USB 2.0 where the maximum allowed is 480 Mb/s.

Solution 1: Try connecting the cameras to different USB host controllers. i.e they should not share the same bus.

Other solutions: to changes the compressed formats, resolutions of the image so that the band width limitation is not breached.

Reference : http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/faq/